# How do I remove the last n characters from a string?

Tags: python

If I have a string and want to remove the last 4 characters of it, how do I do that?

So if I want to remove `.bmp` from `Forest.bmp` to make it just `Forest`
How do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the last four characters or are you trying to remove file extensions?

Comment: If you are dealing with file extensions you should use `os.path.splitext` instead of removing the last 4 characters.

Comment: I am trying to remove just the last 4 characters or the file extension, either one.

Answer (score 44):

Two solutions here.

To remove the last 4 characters in general:

```
s = 'this is a string1234'

s = s[:-4]
```

yields

```
'this is a string'
```

And more specifically geared toward filenames, consider [os.path.splitext()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=splitext#os.path.splitext) meant for splitting a filename into its base and extension:

```
import os 

s = "Forest.bmp"
base, ext = os.path.splitext(s)
```

results in:

```
print base
'Forest'

print ext
'.bmp'
```

Comment: I just copied that into my python shell, and it yields:

Comment: You might have missed the implied "import os" - but they've edited to add it, what's above as of right now works.

Comment: @user1319219 Yes, be sure you have `import os` .. let me know if that doesn't work. My answers are copied straight from the shell so it should be ok.

Comment: @user1319219 If this was helpful answer please consider marking it as answered by clicking on the checkmark. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 Marking questions answered will give both parties some reputation points and indicate that attention can be given to other unanswered questions.