# How do I select part of a filename (leave out the extension) in Python?

Tags: python, string, textselection

For example if I have the variable "file.txt", I want to be able to save only "file" to a variable. What I'd like is to eliminate whatever is beyond the last dot (including the dot). So if i had "file.version2.txt", I'd be left with "file.version2".
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: check this out
[remove last n charecters][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645959/how-do-i-remove-the-last-n-characters-from-a-string

Comment: using a combination of `os.path.basename` and `os.path.splitext` seems a good start

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to use `os.path.splitext`

```
In [3]: os.path.splitext('test.test.txt')
Out[3]: ('test.test', '.txt')
In [4]: os.path.splitext('test.test.txt')[0]
Out[4]: 'test.test'
```

full reference for similar manipulations can be found here http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. All i needed to add was "import os" before using os.path.splitext

Comment: If you got answer then select it as answer :)

Comment: it tells me I have to wait a few minutes, otherwise I would have :)

Comment: if it tells you to wait then you have to ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using the module [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) you can retrieve the full name of the file and then remove the extension:

```
import os
file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path_to_your_file))
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is not too long you can do something like this if the file is in same directory

```
old_f = 'file.version2.txt'
new_f = old_f.split('.')
sep = '.'
sep.join(new_f[:-1]) # or assign it to a variable current_f = sep.join(new_f[:-1])
```