# How to trim the last 10 values from list

Tags: python-3.x, csv, trim, date-formatting, strip

I have a csv file list. Have to trim the last 10 values in python. Below is my code.

```py
s=['SSP_AP_INVOICE_DISTRIBUTIONS_17022023072701.csv','SSP_AP_INVOICE_16022023072701.csv','SSP_HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS_18012023043243.CSV']

import datetime as dt

for i in filename:
 date_str = i.split('_')[4]
 x=date_str[:8]
 print(x)
```

But in my list, few _ have 3rd,4th,5th positions. But I am able to remove from the 4th.I want to remove the last 10 values in list including .csv

But I am expecting Output be like:

```
SSP_AP_INVOICE_DISTRIBUTIONS_17022023 
SSP_AP_INVOICE_16022023 
SSP_HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS_18012023
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove the last n characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645959/how-do-i-remove-the-last-n-characters-from-a-string)

Comment: `for i in filename: print(i[:-10])`